# ошибка при установке babel-polifyll

Tags: babel

[image: babel]

ошибка при установке babel-polifyll

Comment: И что вы не смогли понять из текста ошибки?

Comment: Укажите ошибку и то, что к ней привело, в текстовом виде с помощью кнопки "править"